# How to create a HashMap with custom object as a key?

Tags: elasticsearch, hashmap, elasticsearch-painless

In Elasticsearch, I have an object that contains an array of objects. Each object in the array have `type`, `id`, `updateTime`, `value` fields.

My input parameter is an array that contains objects of the same type but different values and update times. Id like to update the objects with new value when they exist and create new ones when they aren't.

I'd like to use Painless script to update those but keep them distinct, as some of them may overlap. Issue is that I need to use both `type` and `id` to keep them unique. So far I've done it with bruteforce approach, nested `for` loop and comparing elements of both arrays, but I'm not too happy about that.

One of the ideas is to take array from source, build temporary HashMap for fast lookup, process input and later store all objects back into source.

Can I create HashMap with custom object (a class with `type` and `id`) as a key? If so, how to do it? I can't add class definition to the script.

Here's the mapping. All fields are 'disabled' as I use them only as intermidiate state and query using other fields.

```js
{
  "properties": {
    "arrayOfObjects": {
      "properties": {
        "typ": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "id": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "value": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "updated": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example doc.

```js
{
  "arrayOfObjects": [
    {
      "typ": "a",
      "id": "1",
      "updated": "2020-01-02T10:10:10Z",
      "value": "yes"
    },
    {
      "typ": "a",
      "id": "2",
      "updated": "2020-01-02T11:11:11Z",
      "value": "no"
    },
    {
      "typ": "b",
      "id": "1",
      "updated": "2020-01-02T11:11:11Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

And finally part of the script in it's current form. The script does some other things, too, so I've stripped them out for brevity.

```java
if (ctx._source.arrayOfObjects == null) {
    ctx._source.arrayOfObjects = new ArrayList();
}
for (obj in params.inputObjects) {
    def found = false;
    for (existingObj in ctx._source.arrayOfObjects) {
        if (obj.typ == existingObj.typ && obj.id == existingObj.id && isAfter(obj.updated, existingObj.updated)) {
            existingObj.updated = obj.updated;
            existingObj.value = obj.value;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        ctx._source.arrayOfObjects.add([
            "typ": obj.typ,
            "id": obj.id,
            "value": params.inputValue,
            "updated": obj.updated
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your script look like right now? Can you share a few docs too? The relevant parts of the mapping would be nice as well.

Comment: @joe Done. Hope that's enough. I'm happy to add more if needed.

Comment: Thanks, that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's technically nothing suboptimal about your approach.

A `HashMap` could potentially save some time but since you're scripting, you're already bound to its innate inefficiencies... Btw [here's how](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-operators-reference.html#map-initialization-operator) you initialize & work with HashMaps.

Another approach would be to rethink your data structure -- instead of arrays of objects use keyed objects or similar. Arrays of objects aren't great for frequent updates.

Finally a tip: you said that these fields are only used to store some intermediate state. If that weren't the case (or won't be in the future), I'd recommend using [`nested`](http://array) arrays to enable querying independently of other objects in the [array](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html).

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'll probably leave it at that. Creating dynamic keys in ES has it's own problems and I like the simplicity of this data structure. About the docs, tho - I know them, just it's uncler to me how to create multi-value key. Docs have only existing types there. Main question was how could I create a key with multiple values (here type and id)? Technically I can concatenate them, but having object would be more elegant, I think.